# Simplify visual basic application in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I have to try to create a function using the VBA in MS Excel.
I have a problem that I need to check the value of some variable and decide to give the output refer to the variable.

example:

```
 Var1 with value SB and B
 var2 with value SB and B
if Var1 = sb and var2 = sb then
 msgbox "SB for Var1 and var2"
elseif var1 =sb and var2=b then
 msgbox "SB var 1 and b var2"
elseif var1 =b and var2=sb then
 msgbox "var1 b and var2 sb"
elseif var1 =b and var2=b then
 msgbox "B for var1 and var2"
endif.
```

is there any suggestion I want to create 6 variable with 3 values, how to simplify the code so I don't need write the code in 729 line.

Comment: use arrays `Var1`, `Var2`, etc., should be `var(1), var(2)` etc. Then loops can eliminate the code repetition.

Comment: What's your overall goal?

Answer (score 0):

@John Coleman, thanks for your advice.
@user3598756 my gool is just showed the output depending to value of variable (as my example.)

i have an idea to use multi demention array but i can't find the syntax for it. i just see singel line array.